# incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to ObservableBooleanValue

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx, listener

I am trying to set a listener to disable a button on a boolean condition using the code below, but I keep on getting an error saying

```
boolean can't be converted to ObervableBooleanValue
```

```java
@FXML
public void initialize() { 
    xBtn.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.not(model.booleanCondition()));
}
```

Below code works, but when the `booleanCondition` is `true`, then it is set to `false` again, the button remains enabled!

```
if (model.booleanCondition()) {xBtn.setDisable(false);}
```

Comment: What does `model.booleanCondition()` return? A plain `boolean`, or a `BooleanProperty`?

Comment: @James_D it returns a plain boolean, here is the booleanCondidtion:       
public boolean booleanCondition() {
        for (X x : y)
            if (!booleanCondition(x))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

Comment: You can't bind to a plain boolean value. There is no way for it to be observed. You need your model to give you access to an `ObservableBooleanValue` of some kind (e.g. a `BooleanProperty`). See http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107. Post the code for your model class if you need more help.

Comment: @James_D - here is the model class boolean condition:: `public boolean booleanCondition() { for (X x : y) if (!booleanCondition(x)) return false; return true; }`

Comment: Don't post code in comments: [edit] your question to include it. As I said, you need to use JavaFX properties in the model if you want to use a binding. Read the tutorial linked in the previous comment.